# Is "far from the end" correct?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Is it right to say *far from the end* in the following example?

> Researches on the exploitation of the DAS method are far from the end.

Comment: This isn't idiomatic; 'far from at an end' or 'far from complete' are.

Comment: ‘Far from the end’ by itself is perfectly fine—but if research on DAS method exploitation is far from the end, then I wonder what would be the more extreme things that are to come after it. Something like “Chemical warfare is far from the end—before this is over, we’ll have a full-on nuclear war!” (while perhaps somewhat defeatist and gloomy) is a more likely context in which to use it.

Comment: ‘Far from the end’ is intensely non-idiomatic.  If for some bizarre reason, the OP wants to use a tricky double-negative, it's just "far from complete" as Edwin explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using complicated double-negatives is an incredibly bad idea in any sort of scientific or engineer writing.

Simply say:

```
Research on the exploitation of the DAS method have only just begun.
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNPAM5ABhvs

Similar phrases include "it is early days" or "is a new field" or "is a fledgling field" or "is only getting underway."

IF that is what you mean. Try to state exactly what you mean, literally, using quantification.  For example...

"Research on DAS began only in 2012 with about 8 papers published so far." or "Research on DAS should take 10 years, but research has only been underway for 6 months."

Your current sentence tells us nothing, you know?

If you must use a double-negative, just use "far from complete" as Edwin explains.

But note that research tends not to **have a "goal"**, so, it makes little sense (probably) to say **anything at all** in relation to the **"end"**.  (For example, can you state, what year, it will end?)

So, it's very likely what you are probably trying to say is that it is early days, that it is a new field.

In short

(1) forget about complicated double-negatives in anything scientific

(2) it's extremely unlikely there is actually an "end" relevant

(3) simply, state - accurately, using numbers - what you mean.

For example, note that as a reader **I literally do not know what you mean**.  in fact I am now curious, how long has this research been going on?  How many people are active, how many papers have been published, what time-scale do you guess for real results?

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression you need is:

- far from (being) [conclusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conclusive). (from TFD)

> - Serving to put an end to doubt, question, or uncertainty; decisive.

'EPA Evidence on Warming Far From [Conclusive](http://www.newsmax.com/LarryBell/EPA-Evidence-Warming-Conclusive/2014/02/28/id/555356/)'

Source: www.newsmax.com

Comment: ...if the goal of the researches is indeed to settle the question +1

Comment: But researches can also try to explore a new field and in such a situation _far from (being) conclusive_ wouldn't fit.

Comment: This seems entirely wrong.  the question has nothing to do with whether the research is "good" or not - the OP is simply trying to say "it has only just begun."